# Using MongoDB/NodeJS, how can I increment by the number of documents modified in an update query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, updates, increment

I have written an update query in MongoDB/NodeJS that deletes objects from an array of a document, based on the parameters I define. After I pull these objects, I would like to to increment another variable in the document based on how many documents were modified by the update query.

Here is an example of one of my events documents:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("575ed7fca7b89bb4027dded9"),
        "dateCreated" : "6/13/2016",
        "latitude" : "56.294786195890076",
        "longitude" : "-43.59161567687988",
        "instructorName" : "Test User",
        "instructorEmail" : "test@user.com",
        "instructorRating" : 5,
        "eventName" : "We gon exercise",
        "eventDescription" : "We gon exercise",
        "spacesAvailable" : 15,
        "streetAddress" : "123 wer",
        "city" : "rty",
        "state" : "NY",
        "zip" : "12332",
        "date" : "06/21/2016",
        "startTime" : "12:00",
        "endTime" : "02:10",
        "tags" : [
                "Cardio",
                "Crossfit"
        ],
        "price" : 5,
        "attendies" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5759cfcdb71d80fb2d1203ef"),
                        "name" : "Buddy Loester",
                        "email" : "Bud18@gmail.com",
                        "timeStamp" : 1467048318510,
                        "payed" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("574f257b05086e2c7f7940ca"),
                        "name" : "Trainer Trainer",
                        "email" : "trainer@user.com",
                        "timeStamp" : 1467055627894,
                        "payed" : true
                }
        ],
        "unpayed" : 0
}
```

Here is my code to give a better visualization:

```
var eventCollection = req.db.get('events');

// get current time since epoch in milliseconds
var milliSinceEpoch = new Date().getTime();

eventCollection.update(
{"attendies.payed" : {$eq : false}},
{
  $pull:
    {
      "attendies" : {"timeStamp": {$lt: milliSinceEpoch /*- 600000*/}}
    }, 
  $inc:
    {
      spacesAvailable: numberAffected
    }
}, 
{
  multi: true
}, function(err, numberAffected) {

    console.log(numberAffected);

    return res.end();

   }
);
```

If I specify 'numberAffected' in the query portion to '1', then it works as expected and increments by 1. However, I would like to increment by the number affected.

I know this code will not work with 'numberAffected' in the query. Using 'numberAffected' in the callback actually does return the number of documents modified by my query.

Does there exist a way in MongoDB to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by rewriting the query. It is as follows:

```
    var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
    var eventCollection = req.db.get('events');
    var milliSinceEpoch = new Date().getTime(); 

    // find and return all the documents in the events DB where there is a user who has not payed for an event
    // they RSVP'd for
    eventCollection.find({"attendies.payed" : {$eq : false}}, function(err, documentsWithUnpayedUsers) {

        // if error finding, print it and return 
        if(err) {
          console.log(err); 
          return res.sendStatus(400, "Error cancelling");
        }

        // if everyone has payed for all RSVP'd events
        if(!documentsWithUnpayedUsers) return res.sendStatus(404, "Everyone has payed!");

        // loop through every document which has people who have not yet payed for RSVP'd events
        for(var i = 0; i < documentsWithUnpayedUsers.length; i++) {

          // for each of these documents: 
          eventCollection.update(
            {_id: ObjectID(documentsWithUnpayedUsers[i]._id)},
            {
              // remove the user from the attendie list if they have not payed, 
              // and it has been 10 minutes since they RSVP'd
              $pull:
                {
                  "attendies" : {"timeStamp": {$lt: milliSinceEpoch - 600000}, "payed" : {$eq : false}}
                },
              // then modify the number of spaces available for the event by the number of people who were 
              // removed from the attendie list
              // then modify the amount of people who have not payed for the event yet (will now be 0)
              $inc:
                {
                  spacesAvailable: documentsWithUnpayedUsers[i].unpayed,
                  unpayed: -documentsWithUnpayedUsers[i].unpayed
                }
            }, function(err) {
                 // error checking for the update query
                 if(err){
                   console.log(err); 
                   return res.sendStatus(400, "There was an error removing an attendie fom the event: " 
                    + documentsWithUnpayedUsers[i].eventName);
                 }
               }
          ); // end of update query
        } // end of for loop

        return res.end();

       }
    ); // end of find()
  }); // end of checkPayed
```